# Node Testing and Port 3000

Tags: nodejs

I am using node to test solidity with a ReactJS front end. After IPFS required I used a SSL I had to add some changes to my nginx conf and now port 3000 is not being found.

I installed the SSL and nginx -t is all ok. Here is my congif file:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
listen 8080;
listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

root /usr/share/nginx/html/ipfs/src;
index App.js index.html index.htm;
listen   443 ssl;
server_name jenbil.com;
ssl    on;
ssl_certificate    /home/keys/jenbil.com.chained.crt;
ssl_certificate_key    /home/keys/jenbil.key;
```

When I try to access https://jenbil.com:3000 I get a not found error but http://jenbil.com works and also https://jenbil.com displays the ReactJS but no actual action is performed.

I am using npm start to run the development server.

Here is netstat -nltp:

```
root@ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled# netstat -nltp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1287/sshd       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      24017/nginx     
tcp        0      0 104.236.58.158:8545     0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8702/geth       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      24017/nginx     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      24017/nginx     
tcp        0      1 104.236.58.158:47508    93.108.217.34:*         SYN_SENT    8702/geth       
tcp        0      1 104.236.58.158:35970    66.41.106.197:*         SYN_SENT    8702/geth       
tcp        0      1 104.236.58.158:52430    124.176.170.179:*       SYN_SENT    8702/geth       
tcp        0      1 104.236.58.158:38030    86.155.52.143:*         SYN_SENT    8702/geth       
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1287/sshd       
tcp6       0      0 :::3000                 :::*                    LISTEN      23874/node      
tcp6       0      0 :::30303                :::*                    LISTEN      8702/geth       
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      24017/nginx     
root@ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled#
```

How can I get the 3000 port to be listened to or how can I not use that anyway in testing?

Answer (score 1):

```
https=true npm start
```

solves the immediate problem.